# Scraping data from a dynamic web database with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am new to Python and am currently trying to figure out how to scrape data from this web:

https://www.entsoe.eu/db-query/consumption/mhlv-a-specific-country-for-a-specific-month

I am not sure if I use Scrapy, BeautifulSoup or Selenium. Need data for a specific country (say DE - Germany) for each month and day within 2012-2014.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: We like to say here that Stack Overflow is "not a code-this-for-me site". However, your last two questions have not shown any research effort, and in response two readers have given you excellent answers anyway (though with several downvotes on this one). Please allow me to encourage you to research these problems first, as it will make you a more self-sufficient programmer. Now, if you find yourself working on a scraper and you get stuck, by all means ask a question featuring code - we like that sort of post here!

Comment: I do know you don't like this kind of comments either. Understood.  I will follow the rules. I know, the guys did a tremendous job. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (for maintaining a web-scraping session) + [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (for HTML parsing) + regex for extracting a value of a javascript variable containing the desired data inside a `script` tag and [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for making a python list out of js list:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.entsoe.eu/db-query/consumption/mhlv-a-specific-country-for-a-specific-month"
payload = {
    'opt_period': '0',
    'opt_Country': '12',  # 12 stands for DE here
    'opt_Month': '1',
    'opt_Year': '2014',
    'opt_Response': '1',
    'send': 'send',
    'opt_period': '0'
}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers
    session.get(url)

    response = session.post(url, data=payload)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile(r'Ext.onReady')).text

    data = literal_eval(re.search(r"var myData = (.*?);", script, re.MULTILINE).group(1))
    for row in data:
        print row
```

Prints:

```
['DE', '2014-01-01', 45424, 43537, 41773, 40716, 39945, 39014, 37282, 37573, 38225, 40639, 42884, 45332, 46285, 45671, 45293, 45840, 48863, 53721, 54607, 53691, 51219, 49701, 49099, 45850]
['DE', '2014-01-02', 42468, 40217, 39564, 39758, 41054, 43586, 48705, 54691, 58650, 61110, 62773, 64309, 64561, 63807, 62706, 61919, 63338, 66760, 66615, 64653, 60690, 57825, 55697, 51490]
['DE', '2014-01-03', 47538, 45125, 44358, 44748, 45815, 48024, 52151, 57564, 60767, 62425, 63654, 65152, 65273, 63591, 62195, 61722, 63311, 66785, 66668, 64317, 60460, 57727, 56084, 52332]
...
['DE', '2014-01-29', 57605, 55275, 54154, 54226, 55320, 58459, 66647, 73890, 75957, 75958, 76725, 77446, 76852, 76362, 75300, 74549, 73958, 77129, 78240, 76323, 71961, 68595, 66088, 61923]
['DE', '2014-01-30', 58207, 56235, 54953, 54873, 55861, 58952, 66756, 73747, 75479, 75507, 76249, 76763, 76013, 75291, 73975, 73267, 72717, 76181, 77765, 76038, 71807, 68369, 65580, 61414]
['DE', '2014-01-31', 57870, 55665, 54381, 54422, 55419, 58490, 65929, 72706, 74666, 74392, 74791, 74923, 73877, 72205, 70449, 69596, 69345, 73259, 74950, 72959, 68623, 65319, 63414, 59467]
```

Selenium-specific approach would be less "magical", but I think this is more than enough for you to start (and for a question with minimal research effort).